# Swift Package Manager (package successfully added, but Module not found)

Tags: swift, xcode, postgresql

I'm new in Swift. I want to create iOS app that can connect to PostgreSQL database. First I found library https://github.com/vapor/postgresql.git that should be added to my project via Swift Package Manager. Using [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7242045-swift-package-manager-for-ios) I added required library to my project successfully (File -> Swift Packages -> Add Package Dependency):
[list of added packages from SPM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh6sC.png)
But when I try to import this module into my view controller, Xcode shows error that module is not found:
[not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K441X.png)

I tried several times to rebuild my project, created new project just for testing this issue. Also I found information about build phases and added this lib as a dependency:
[build phases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPaX6.png)
But I still get error: "No such module PostgreSQL".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi there, why you need to access directly this PostgreSQL? Why not use an API? It is less painful and controllable.

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde Hi! I don't need direct access, I'm okay to use API. I'm just looking for any way to reach my goal. Can you share some more information about API?

Comment: See if you find [something here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=swift+api+connection) practice and share with us you code doubts. And we will be happy to help with your code. And take a time to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by myself. I compiled C static library "libpq" (can be found in PostgreSQL sources) and added it to my swift project. Included this library by adding special bridging header file. Finally I got what I wanted. 
P.S. If someone what to repeat, he or she should know: static C library must be compiled for iOS device architecture (and also in iOS simulator architecture which differs from iOS device arch.).